# Importing values from external file using `include

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

I want to define a set of global parameter values in an external file and import them into a Verilog (not SystemVerilog) file. How can I do that? I know this can be done using pkg in VHDL, and I am expecting something similar.

I am trying this:

For the main module:

```
        module temp (
        `include "file.vh"
        input [WIDTH:0] data_in,
        output reg [WIDTH:0] data_out,
        input clk
    );
        always @(posedge clk) begin
            data_out <= data_in;
        end
    endmodule
```

and a `file.vh` file:

```
    `define WIDTH = 12;
```

Please correct me here as this code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors in your code.  You are confusing `define` macro syntax with `parameter` syntax.  I'll assume you want macros.  These changes will fix the errors.

For file `file.vh`, use:

```
`define WIDTH 12
```

For the module, use:

```
`include "file.vh"

module temp (
        input      [`WIDTH:0] data_in,
        output reg [`WIDTH:0] data_out,
        input clk
    );
        always @(posedge clk) begin
            data_out <= data_in;
        end
endmodule
```

`define` macros use simple text substitution.  You want to replace the `WIDTH` text with only the number `12`; you do not want to use `=` or `;`.

When you use the macro in the module, you need to prepend the backtick:

```
`WIDTH
```